# How to change the index of a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

## Current dataframe

I have created a dataframe (df) as below:

[image]

## Expected dataframe

I want to change the index of my dataframe as below without changing the values

[image]

I tried setindex , reindex but not getting the desired result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set index as shown below

```
>>> idx = pd.Index(['s7', 's8', 's9', 's10', 's11'])
>>> idx
Index(['s7', 's8', 's9', 's10', 's11'], dtype='object')
>>> df.set_index(idx)
     Height  Weight
s7      167     108
s8      107     180
s9      134     187
s10     147     176
s11     160     198
>>>
```

Comment: df.set_index returns a new dataframe. did you assign it back to df?